# Rails - Get Params like "cart_item[price]=5%2C70€" out of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My View make a redirect an pass the Params

> ?cart_item[price]=5%2C70€

.
I try to get this with

> @price = [:cart_item][:price]

, but there i get the error "can't convert Symbol into Integer".
I try it with codes like ":cart_item_price" or ":cart_item.price" but always no variable was founded

How can i get this price in my other action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to get this with
>   @price = [:cart_item][:price]

I think you need to put an object before this `[:cart_item][:price]`. Maybe `params`?

```
@price = params[:cart_item][:price]
```

Comment: i try to send only a number, but there is with "@price = [:cart_item][:price]" the same error "can't convert Symbol into Integer".

Comment: May be `params` ? Its definitely `params` :) Lol

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting something in your code.

What you must do is `@price = params[:cart_item][:price]` this should work.
Also ensure you check if the key `cart_item` exists before you assign the value to the price variable. 
Something like this should work `@price = params[:cart_item][:price] if params[:cart_item]`

You have omitted the params hash to extract the value from. Hence the error.

Hope that helps.